# Не получается записать куки

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, cookie

Было реализовано переключение вида товаров. А я хочу при клике записывать куки, чтобы потом при переключении на другую страницу, вид сохранялся.

```
document.cookie = "productbox=grid";
```

Но куки почему-то не сохраняются. В чем может быть проблема?

```
jQuery('.product-view-button .grid').click(function(){
    jQuery('.product-js').removeClass('product-box-flex');  
    jQuery('.product-js').addClass('product-box');
        jQuery('.product-view-button .list').removeClass('active');  
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');
        jQuery('.product-block').removeClass('col-md-12 col-lg-12').addClass('col-md-6 col-lg-4');
        document.cookie = "productbox=grid";
        return false; 
    });
```

Comment: Вы не указали путь. Из документации `;path=path (e.g., '/', '/mydir') If not specified, defaults to the current path of the current document location.`. Грубо говоря, куки записалось, но `path` равен пути той страницы где Вы его записывали. Подробнее можете почитать [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_cookie). Также вместо cookie можно использовать local storage.

Comment: Исправил, добавил path, но запись имеет вот такой вид. И всё равно куки нет в консоли почему-то

`jQuery('.product-view-button .grid').click(function(){
  jQuery('.product-js').removeClass('product-box-flex');  
  jQuery('.product-js').addClass('product-box');
        jQuery('.product-view-button .list').removeClass('active');  
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');
        jQuery('.product-block').removeClass('col-md-12 col-lg-12').addClass('col-md-6 col-lg-4');
        document.cookie = "productblock=list;path=/"; 
        return false; 
    });`